# How to display snapshots with Name key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to set my region and display all my snapshots that start with the name `Snaps`. I got the region, but how do I get the name key to display for my snapshots?
Here's what I have so far:

```
import boto3
my_session = boto3.session.Session(region_name = 'us-east-1')
my_region = my_session.region_name
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Filters` in [`describe_snapshots`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots),

```
my_session = boto3.session.Session(region_name = 'us-east-1')
ec2 = my_session.client('ec2')
snapshot_response = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['Snaps*']}])

# To print only the Name of the snapshots
for snapshot in snapshot_response['Snapshots']:
    for tag in snapshot['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            print tag['Value']
            break
```

Comment: awesome! One more question. I tried to print and it displayed alot of other information. How can i print to screen with just the Name?

Comment: Frank - that works great, but just checked my AWS account and see that there are six snapshots with 'Snaps*', but the code only shows four. Any idea why it wouldn't show all of them? (the Snaps were created with same AWS account)

Comment: It would if they all are in the same region and starts with `Snaps..` (case sensitive). Can you check the case of the names?

Comment: I think I know what's happening. My default region is us-west-2, but I thought I set the region in this code using:

     my_session = boto3.session.Session(region_name = 'us-east-1')
     my_region = my_session.region_name

(us-west-2 has four snapshots, but us-east-1 has six) How do I use my_region to pull the list of snapshots?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137580/discussion-between-cwhitmore-and-franklinsijo).